# Help and Improvement queue is empty?

Tags: discussion, help-improvement

I logged on this morning to find the [H&I queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/helper) not at the usual 300+ posts needing review but actually empty.  What happened over the weekend?  Did something get fixed, or were people just really productive in this queue?  Or am I just seeing things with some sort of messed up connection?

Comment: Just look at the [history page](http://stackoverflow.com/review/helper/history) to see what happened.

Comment: @HansPassant that only shows my history (a whopping 2 reviews).  It's the same as the "my review history" with my userid as a url paramter.

Comment: @HansPassant, it only shows the reviews I did myself there, presumably because I don't have 10k rep needed to view the full history. So what _did_ happen ?

Comment: Just a bunch of users keeping themselves very busy, each dusting off ~20 questions each.  Nothing special.

Comment: Well, maybe review some Low Quality Posts today instead. Maybe we can get _all_ the queues (well, except close obviously) to 0 items ?

Comment: @HansPassant I guess I do think that's special since it was chronically full of tasks.  And it's being managed now.